# curl post fail all time

Tags: api, curl, post, request

hello i'm trying this guide but it fail all time

https://github.com/ubahnverleih/WoBike/blob/master/Beam.md

To login, I need to get OTP code but i can't access to it

```
curl -d "phoneNumber=[phonenumber]countryCode=+[countrycode]" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "User-Agent:escooterapp/latest-app-version;ios" \
-X POST https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/auth/phoneverification
```

but it sends message like this

`{"success":false,"message":"There was some error","response":{},"error":"","data":{}}`

i don't know why this fail
is my code grammarly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial and the curl command say it's an application/json and you are passing an incorrect format in the data. Pay attention at the beginning of the command curl -d ...

**Correct:**

```
curl -d '{"phoneNumber":"<phone-number>","countryCode":"+<country-code>"}' \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "User-Agent:escooterapp/latest-app-version;ios" \
-X POST https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/auth/phoneverification
```

**Wrong:**

```
curl -d "phoneNumber=[phonenumber]countryCode=+[countrycode]" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "User-Agent:escooterapp/latest-app-version;ios" \
-X POST https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/auth/phoneverification
```

**Execution:**

```
 curl -d '{"phoneNumber":"123123123","countryCode":"+55"}' \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -H "User-Agent:escooterapp/latest-app-version;ios" \
 -X POST https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/auth/phoneverification
```

> {"message":"PhoneVerificationServiceErrorDomain","messageKey":1,"messageArgs":"{"status":400,"message":"Invalid
> parameter `To`:
> +55123123123","code":60200,"moreInfo":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200"

Comment: sorry, this is my first post